# Can someone explain to me briefly what is std::streampos?

Tags: c++, stringstream

Can you show me some examples with `std::streampos`?
I am not sure what it is used for and I don't know how to work with it.

I saw in a project in github:

```
std::streampos pos = ss.tellg();
```

where `ss` is `std::stringstream`.

Why don't we use `int pos = ss.tellg()`, for example in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why don't we use int pos = ss.tellg(), for example in this case?

Because `std::streampos` happens to be the type returned by `std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::tellg()`.

Maybe on one computer it's something that converts cleanly to an `int`, but not on another. By using the correct type, your code is platform-independant.

Also note that `std::streampos` is the type returned by the `tellg()` method of that very specific class, not the type returned by `tellg()` methods everywhere. Other streams might very well return a different type instead of `std::streampos`, and you should be accounting for that.

The actual cleanest way to choose the correct type for `pos` is to literally ask the type: "What should I be using to represent positions in the stream?":

```
std::stringstream::pos_type pos = ss.tellg();
```

Or just use `auto` so you don't have to worry about it:

```
auto pos = some_stream.tellg();
```

Comment: so, you say that if I am writing a small program only for me, just for practice it could be ok if I use int?

Comment: @vanderwaal If you only care about running the code once, then as long as it compiles and does what you want, then you do you. But even then, it's good to get into a habit of writing portable code by default. `auto` makes it easy to do the correct thing while still being lazy, so you don't really have much of an excuse.

Comment: [Documentation if you wish to go deeper.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos) If you think the documentation is complicated, you're right. It is. All the more reason to use `auto` and let the system take care of any niggly little details that may blow up in your face like getting the stream position in a file larger than 2 GB on systems where `int` is 32 bit.

Comment: Note that `std::streampos` is *not* an integer type; it defines a conversion to integer type, but it *also* contains multibyte stream state information (necessary when doing text I/O in certain character encodings). So converting to `int` doesn't just cause problems above 2 GB, it *also* discards information that may be necessary if you need to restore the precise state of the stream on a subsequent `seekg` (e.g. omitting the state could mean you're left in the middle of a UTF-8 character, without the information about the prior bytes, so it's impossible to read the character you're in).